# Swift - Sort different arrays accordingly to date array

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 user input fields which each create a different array. These arrays are being used to fill a `UITableViewCell`. My intention is to sort the added cells by date.

One of the input fields contains a date which shall be used to sort this table. To also display the date, the array is of type `String`, hence the dates are formatted to `String`.

Let's say I would not directly format it to `String` and sort it before I do. Is there a way to sort the other arrays according to the Date array?

```
import UIKit

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationView: UITableView!

    var isVisible = false

    var descArray: [String] = []
    var titleArray: [String] = []
    var dateArray: [String] = []
    var typeArray: [Int] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        declareArrays()
        print(dateArray)
        self.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                        forToolbarPosition: .any,
                                        barMetrics: .default)
        self.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
        notificationView.delegate = self
        notificationView.dataSource = self
    }

    func declareArrays() {
        descArray = getDesc()
        titleArray = getTitle()
        dateArray = getDate()
        typeArray = getType()
    }

    func getDesc() -> [String] {
        return descNotificationArray
    }

    func getTitle() -> [String] {
        return titleNotificationArray
    }

    func getDate() -> [String] {
        return dateNotificationArray
    }

    func getType() -> [Int] {
        return notificationTypeArray
    }

    @IBAction func goBack(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToMain", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func addNotification(_ sender: Any) {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToType", sender: self)
    }

}

extension NotificationViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dateArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let date = dateArray[indexPath.row]
        let title = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        let desc = descArray[indexPath.row]
        let notType = typeArray[indexPath.row]

        if notType == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TuvTableViewCell") as! TuvTableViewCell
            cell.setTitle(title: title)
            cell.setDesc(desc: desc)
            cell.setDate(date: date)
            return cell
        } else if notType == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceNotTableViewCell") as! ServiceNotTableViewCell
            cell.setTitle(title: title)
            cell.setDesc(desc: desc)
            cell.setDate(date: date)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewCell") as! NotificationViewCell
            cell.setTitle(title: title)
            cell.setDesc(desc: desc)
            cell.setDate(date: date)
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            dateArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            titleArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            descArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)

            descNotificationArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            dateNotificationArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            titleNotificationArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)

            defaults.set(descNotificationArray, forKey: "descNotificationArray")
            defaults.set(dateNotificationArray, forKey: "dateNotificationArray")
            defaults.set(titleNotificationArray, forKey: "titleNotificationArray")

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I've added an struct and a func which appends the input to the array and sorts it:

```
struct not {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    var Date: Date
}

func appendToStructArray() {
        let notificationData: not = not(title: notifTitle.text!, desc: notifDescribtion.text!, Date: datePicker.date)
        notStructArray.append(notificationData)
        notStructArray.sort(by: { $0.Date < $1.Date })
    }
```

Now in the TableViewController: How do I manage to get the data from one struct inside of the array and add it to a cell just like I did it previously with my arrays?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What is `dateNotificationArray`? If `dateArray` is an array of dates, why is it an array of String?

Comment: This video by Rob Napier talks about *exactly* your problem at 7:14. https://youtu.be/_S6UOrwS-Tg?t=434

Comment: @matt I haven't thought of sorting the array before, that's why I immediately transformed the Date into a String after user input to display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution is to have one array, not four. Create a `struct` with 4 properties. Then have one array of that struct. Then it becomes trivial to add, remove, sort, and filter the array as needed to populate your table view.

Comment: Thank you. I've added my progress to my initial question. How do I manage to get the data from one struct inside of the array and add it to a cell just like I did it previously with my arrays?

Comment: It's no different. `let rowData = notStructArray[indexPath.row]`. Then access the properties of `rowData` to setup the cell much like you were doing. `cell.setTitle(title: rowData.title)`

Comment: Following error appears: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "Fuel_Check.not(title: \"T\U00dcV\", desc: \"N\U00e4chster T\U00dcV Termin\", date: 2019-05-01 18:50:00 +0000, type: 1)"
) for key notStructArray'`

Comment: That's a whole new issue. Do some research on that error. If you need further help with your new issue, please post a new question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

Instead using all those arrays, you might consider using another type that comprises all of those, something like:

```
struct Foo {
  let date: Date
  let desc: String
  let type: String
  let title: String
}
```

Then you would have an array of `foos` that you could sort by date. That way everything would be sorted without the need of handling different arrays.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help. I've added my progress to my initial question. How do I manage to get the data from one struct inside of the array and add it to a cell just like I did it previously with my arrays?

Comment: Just do this in the cell for row: `let not = notStructArray[indexPath.row]` and use `not` to populate the views: `cell.setTitle(not.title)`.